# Good Javascript Cleaner

Tags: javascript, code-cleanup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML formatter/tidy/beautifier for JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913355/html-formatter-tidy-beautifier-for-javascript)

I'm looking for a good automated javascript cleaner (as in locates and fixes errors), similar to the w3c validator's cleaner function (that fixes the javascript errors).

Update: Thanks to a helpful responce I found my solution: Closure Linter.

Comment: @Matt Ball Im looking for a free online serivce that cleans javascript, not a program based in javascript that cleans html

Comment: @Chris, didn't your read the first answer? http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: @Xeon, yes and I went to the site. Im looking for a something that fixes the errors similar to W3C html's tidyclean function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you might be interested in Google's [*Closure Linter*](http://code.google.com/closure/utilities/docs/linter_howto.html), which, like [*JSLint*](http://www.jslint.com/), validates your code and reports problems, but also provides the possibility to fix them:

> (...) you can substitute `fixjsstyle` for `gjslint` to automatically fix many of the errors that `gjslint` checks for.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I'm looking for.....how easy is it to use though?

Comment: @Chris: Have a look at the website. It's very easy, you just have to run `fixjsstyle path/to/file.js` (but also note comment about making backups).

Answer (score 2):

Try [**jsbeautifier** to beautify your code](http://jsbeautifier.org/) and [**jslint** to clean up its syntax](http://www.jslint.com/).

Comment: Looking for something that fixes erros not adds/removes lines/whitespace

Comment: @Chris: you're looking for something to fix errors in your code?  Isn't that called a "programmer"?

Comment: +1 for a golden comment :) (and the right answer to the original question of course).

Comment: @maerics You know one that will fix 347 errors for free lemme know :P

Answer (score 0):

I quite like http://jsbeautifier.org/ for cleaning up Javascript.

This site is also mentioned in the answer provided by Matt in the comments.

Comment: Looking for something that fixes erros not adds/removes lines/whitespace

Comment: You didn't say that in your question. There's a big difference between "cleaning" and actually fixing your errors.

Comment: Sorry, I reedited the question

Comment: also, this site does much more than just add/remove lines/whitespace. I usually use it for de-obfuscating code (and such like).