# Good JavaScript-based tidying for HTML, CSS and JS?

Tags: javascript, open-source, tidy

Can anyone recommend a JavaScript-based code reformatter for HTML, CSS and JS?

I'm making a web-based IDE and I'd like to be able to tidy up some code without having to refresh the page or wait for an ajax request.

Note: I need it to be able to accept and return a string, and not work directly with HTML elements. My IDE doesn't use a `textarea`.

Comment: http://www.davidpirek.com/blog/html-beautifier-jquery-plugin, https://github.com/einars/js-beautify

Comment: @iliacholy, why did you post that as a comment instead of as a full answer? For my understanding, it deserves to be a full answer.

Comment: @Adel: The best kind of grammar Nazi....fixes it him/herself.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a few

- [html beautifier jquery plugin](http://www.davidpirek.com/blog/html-beautifier-jquery-plugin)
- [js-beautify](https://github.com/einars/js-beautify)
- [cssbeautify](https://github.com/senchalabs/cssbeautify)

**[EDIT]:** also found [this](http://static.arantius.com/inc/tabifier.js) script, it's what the html beautifier is based on.

Comment: "html beautifier jquery plugin" Doesn't seem to work. Its returning an "unexpected token" error

Answer (score 2):

HTML tidy is by far the best solution.  Classic binary has been ported to javascript:  [How to format/tidy/beautify in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913355/how-to-format-tidy-beautify-in-javascript/30280786#30280786)

Comment: Playing the [demo](http://lovasoa.github.io/tidy-html5/demo.html), I'm not sure how I feel about it. I think it takes a few too many liberties with your HTML.