# how to clean a HTML content for .innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML formatter/tidy/beautifier for JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913355/html-formatter-tidy-beautifier-for-javascript)

I want to pass HTML code to a div:

```
myDiv.innerHTML = htmlCode;
```

its similar like I was trying to use an IFRAME. The problem is, if a htmlCode is not formatted well (there is a missing `</div>` for example) then it spoils all the page. How to clean those?

Comment: fix it at the source. Don't remedy it.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look:
[google-caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer) — compiler for making third-party HTML, CSS and JavaScript safe for embedding

Answer (score 2):

You could first use a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser) object to convert the HTML code to a DOM structure. That will fix any broken markup. You can then insert the resulting DOM structure as a child to your div.

Be careful, though: Embedding HTML code from an untrusted source is very dangerous, because it allows [Cross Site Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Site-Scripting) attacks.