# Is it possible to format an ugly HTML code using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For Example I have a code like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /><title>Untitled Document</title></head><body></body></html>
```

Above ugly code output after source format using javascript like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Test</p>
    <b>Test Format</b>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me on this.....Thanks

Comment: can't the "provider" of the source beautify it before serving it?

Comment: this can solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913355/how-to-format-tidy-beautify-in-javascript