# How to beautify the html tags using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to align the html tags which is coming from backend php.How to neatly align and show that the html tags to the user.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <style type="text/css">
      .attach_btn{font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700; color: #fefefe; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; padding: 8px 16px; border-radius: 3px; background: #243f89; border: none; border-color: #243f89;}p{margin:10px 0; padding:0;}table{border-collapse:collapse;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{display:block; margin:0; padding:0;}img,a img{border:0; height:auto; outline:none; text-decoration:none;}body,#bodyTable,#bodyCell{height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; width:100%;}.mcnPreviewText{display:none !important;}#outlook a{padding:0;}img{-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;}table{mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;}
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <title>Purple Admin</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/iconfonts/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/css/vendor.bundle.base.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container-scroller">
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can beautify your html online, there are lots of html beautifier tools like https://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html

Comment: User will not see ( or care) your html tags . The best way is format in backend before sending to client ...

Comment: Then how to format the html tags in backend using php(that html tags are in database)

Comment: @DavidJapan formatting on back-end won't work too, if you're sending it with a string, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this using javascript [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```js
var htmlstr='<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head> <style type="text/css"> .attach_btn{font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700; color: #fefefe; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; padding: 8px 16px; border-radius: 3px; background: #243f89; border: none; border-color: #243f89;}p{margin:10px 0; padding:0;}table{border-collapse:collapse;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{display:block; margin:0; padding:0;}img,a img{border:0; height:auto; outline:none; text-decoration:none;}body,#bodyTable,#bodyCell{height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; width:100%;}.mcnPreviewText{display:none !important;}#outlook a{padding:0;}img{-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;}table{mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;}<meta charset="utf-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"> <title>Purple Admin</title> <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/iconfonts/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/css/vendor.bundle.base.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png"/></head><body> <div class="container-scroller"> </body></html>';

htmlstr = htmlstr.split(/\>[ ]?\</).join(">\n<");

htmlstr = htmlstr.split(/([*]?\{|\}[*]?\{|\}[*]?)/).join("\n");

htmlstr = htmlstr.split(/[*]?\;/).join("\;\n    ");

document.body.innerText= htmlstr;
```

You can use this function to beauty your HTML & CSS, but not guaranteed to JavaScript:

```js
function beautifycode(htmlstr){
    htmlstr = htmlstr.split(/\>[ ]?\</).join(">\n<");
    htmlstr = htmlstr.split(/([*]?\{|\}[*]?\{|\}[*]?)/).join("\n");
    htmlstr = htmlstr.split(/[*]?\;/).join("\;\n    ");
    return htmlstr;
}
var mystr='<html><head><title>Title</title><style>.container{background:#959595;color:#fff} a{color: red;}</style></head><body><div class="container">do click on <a href="#">Link</a></div></body></html>';
document.body.innerText= beautifycode(mystr);
```

Comment: Its working fine,but its not working for <div> and <table> tags

Comment: I just given you hint in answer that how to format your code using Regex, you have to use more Regex to beautify code more. Or you can also beautify code at https://htmlformatter.com/ , it is better than adding lot of Regex to our JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

I had a requirement like this before. Thankfully, I was able to find one library which did this (proper indentation for better readability). Hope this proves helpful to you too:

```
<script src='http://lovasoa.github.io/tidy-html5/tidy.js'></script>
<script>
  options = {
  "indent":"auto",
  "indent-spaces":2,
  "wrap":80,
  "markup":true,
  "output-xml":false,
  "numeric-entities":true,
  "quote-marks":true,
  "quote-nbsp":false,
  "show-body-only":true,
  "quote-ampersand":false,
  "break-before-br":true,
  "uppercase-tags":false,
  "uppercase-attributes":false,
  "drop-font-tags":true,
  "tidy-mark":false
}

var html = document.querySelector("body").outerHTML;
var result = tidy_html5(html, options);
console.log(result);
</script>
```

Source: [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30280786/1223045)