# Showing table code in textarea by using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want show the table code in textarea when page loads. My following code doing that for me but I want my showed code must have opening and closing table tag. Please tell me how I can do that!

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("myTable");

            var targetId = "_hiddenCopyText_";
            var isInput = elem.tagName === "INPUT" || elem.tagName === "TEXTAREA";
            var origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd;
                            target = elem;
                origSelectionStart = elem.selectionStart;
                origSelectionEnd = elem.selectionEnd;
            
         document.getElementById("showTableCode").value=elem.innerHTML.replaceAll("<tbody>", '').replaceAll("</tbody>", '').replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n){2,}/g, '\n');
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<center>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table></center>

<br>

<center><b>Your Table Code:</b><br>
<textarea cols="50" id="showTableCode" rows="10">
</textarea></center>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply get the [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) of the table like this:

```js
elem.parentNode
```

Then it will provide the whole table HTML code for you since you pointing to its parent and getting its `innerHTML`.

So your final code should be something like this:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("myTable");

var targetId = "_hiddenCopyText_";
var isInput = elem.tagName === "INPUT" || elem.tagName === "TEXTAREA";
var origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd;
target = elem;
origSelectionStart = elem.selectionStart;
origSelectionEnd = elem.selectionEnd;

document.getElementById("showTableCode").value = elem.parentNode.innerHTML.replaceAll("<tbody>", '').replaceAll("</tbody>", '').replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n){2,}/g, '\n');
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <center>
    <table id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </center>

  <br>

  <center>
    <b>Your Table Code:</b><br>
    <textarea cols="50" id="showTableCode" rows="10"></textarea>
  </center>


</body>

</html>
```

Or by a simpler approach, you can do this with [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) instead of [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). Which provides the parent wrapping element of your desirable block also.

So the whole thing will be something like this:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("myTable");

var targetId = "_hiddenCopyText_";
var isInput = elem.tagName === "INPUT" || elem.tagName === "TEXTAREA";
var origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd;
target = elem;
origSelectionStart = elem.selectionStart;
origSelectionEnd = elem.selectionEnd;

document.getElementById("showTableCode").value = elem.outerHTML.replaceAll("<tbody>", '').replaceAll("</tbody>", '').replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n){2,}/g, '\n');
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <center>
    <table id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </center>

  <br>

  <center>
    <b>Your Table Code:</b><br>
    <textarea cols="50" id="showTableCode" rows="10"></textarea>
  </center>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Dude your 1st snippet is wrong please check here https://jsfiddle.net/tsoe4dLj/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `outerHTML` instead of `innerHTML`:

```
elem = document.getElementById("myTable");

            var targetId = "_hiddenCopyText_";
            var isInput = elem.tagName === "INPUT" || elem.tagName === "TEXTAREA";
            var origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd;
                            target = elem;
                origSelectionStart = elem.selectionStart;
                origSelectionEnd = elem.selectionEnd;
            
         document.getElementById("showTableCode").value=elem.outerHTML.replaceAll("<tbody>", '').replaceAll("</tbody>", '').replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n){2,}/g, '\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```js
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
let area = document.getElementById("showTableCode");
// For the origins of the format function please check this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913355/how-to-format-tidy-beautify-in-javascript/3966736 
function format(html) {
  var tab = '  ';
  var result = '';
  var indent = '';

  html.split(/>\s*</).forEach(function(element) {
    if (element !== "tbody") {
      if (element.match(/^\/\w/)) {
        indent = indent.substring(tab.length);
      }

      result += indent + '<' + element + '>\r\n';

      if (element.match(/^<?\w[^>]*[^\/]$/)) {
        indent += tab;
      }
    }

  });

  return result.substring(1, result.length - 3);
}

area.value = format(table.outerHTML);
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <center>
    <table id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </center>

  <br>

  <center><b>Your Table Code:</b><br>
    <textarea cols="50" id="showTableCode" rows="10">
</textarea></center>


</body>

</html>
```